# how to get good looking copyright and registered symbols

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'm trying to include copyright © or registered ® symbols in my document. However they look terrible! As far as I can tell it is generating a small caps letter with a big circle around it (not even centered).

I have tried using `\textregistered` and also using `[utf]{inputenc}` and putting the symbol in directly... they both look the same.

[image]

I am using `[utopia]{mathdesign}` for the fonts - perhaps this is something to do with it?

Comment: You can use \copyright for ©

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Use the `textcomp` package, which offers a `\textregistered` symbol (both serif and sans-serif), different to standard LaTeX which uses `\textcircled`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\textregistered\textcopyright
\sffamily\textregistered\textcopyright
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Here are the original LaTeX definitions from latex.ltx:

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textcopyright}{\textcircled{c}}
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textregistered}{\textcircled{%
      \check@mathfonts\fontsize\sf@size\z@\math@fontsfalse\selectfont R}}
```

If designed symbols like those of textcomp wouldn't fit to your text font, you could use `\textcircled` similarly to create a symbol with the used font together with some correction if necessary, with [`\raisebox`](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-302.html) etc.

For ConTeXt, use the `\registered{}` and `\trademark{}` macros.

Comment: How can a professional type-setting system like latex ship with a copyright symbol that by default is a "c" with a circle around? That sounds perverted :)

Comment: Thanks -- this makes them look a lot better! (I also think it's strange that it doesn't use a glyph from a font but perhaps the older fonts don't have them)

Comment: @lifb Backwards compatibility with seven-bit font encodings from the ’80s.

Comment: As of 2019, you should be able to use © and ® in your UTF-8 source code. (LaTeX changed the default input encoding in April 2018.) If you’re using `textcomp`, you probably also want to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: Also note that `textcomp` loads the TS1-encoded page of your font if it has one, and most 8-bit font packages do. So you will rarely if ever need to fall back on `\textcircled` to get a matching © and ® for your current font.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that TS1 encoded symbols are provided by default since 2020 and `textcomp` isn't necessary any more.

Answer (score 25):

I know it's a very old post but I found another solution which provides an output almost equal to

```
$^{\tiny{\textregistered}}$
```

but without using the math environment

```
Matlab\textsuperscript{\tiny\textregistered}
```

My minimal working example (MWE) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}
Before: Matlab\textregistered

After: Matlab\,\textsuperscript{\tiny\textregistered}
\end{document}
```

My preferred version leaves a bit more non-breaking space between Matlab and the registered symbol.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) I rephrased your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077).

Comment: I had the registered symbol in a section title which gave me a warning "Token not allowed in a PDF string. Apparently, there was a problem with hyperref. Found a solution [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21879).

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, found even better syntax: `\subsection{Bluetooth\texorpdfstring{$^®$}{} Protocols}`

Comment: Looks good without \tiny too `\textsuperscript{\textregistered}`. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Many professional fonts have dedicated glyphs for the copyright and registered symbols, so if you are using a font like that you can simply use those glyphs. Some of the fonts available for free with TeX include these symbols - I checked Palantino, Utopia and Charter, they all have them.  Most professional fonts I have seen have them.

The \copyright command defined in the TeXBook was a superposition of two characters, which is never going to look as good as a specifically-designed glyph. But copyright symbols are rare in mathematics publishing, apart from the copyright page, so it was probably a case of "good enough", particularly because of the font limitations of early TeX.

Comment: How do I use them? When I put unicode copyright symbol in it just did the same as \textcopyright

Comment: In mathdesign (tested with utopia) and mathpazo, all I had to do is load the textcomp package, and the \copyright symbol automatically was replaced by the symbol from the font file.

Answer (score 6):

I tried

```
MATLAB\textsuperscript \textregistered / Simulink
```

which resulted in

```
MATLAB®/ Simulink
```

as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
$^{\tiny{\textregistered}}$
```

It will look as expected.

Answer (score 5):

You asked back in 2010, and got a great answer that still works.  As of 2019, I would recommend you use Unicode fonts for new documents and compile with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  Only a few publishers still don’t support that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\textregistered\textcopyright
\textsf{\textregistered\textcopyright}

©®\textsf{©®}
\end{document}
```

[image: Font Sample]

Answer (score 3):

getting inspired by all of you:

```
\textsuperscript{\textregistered}
```

works for me, even without typing

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

hope it works for you guys as well!

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Matlab}$^{\circledR}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, you could use Charmap to copy and paste ASCII 174 character that will look the same as `\registered` but not swallow the following blank space.