# How to get \copyright when mixing T1 fonts and fontspec?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, luatex, font-encodings

This example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\copyright 2011
\end{document}
```

Gives:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \copyright unavailable in encoding T1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \copyright
               2011
?
```

What can I do to get a copyright symbol? Is there another command I should use perhaps?

Comment: Yey a downvote without a comment. Clearly I have misunderstood something here because I am not supposed to ask this question... 
I have received a lot of helpfull answers for which I am thankful. However they all give me the distinct feelign that I in fact have not understood what I am doing. Perhaps there is some document around that can explain to me what I am doing and why that is such a bad thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick solution:

Use `\textcopyright` instead of `\copyright`. Now the copyright sign will be ouput in `cmsy` font, and there will be a font warning.

This approach is somewhat bad because it produces a font substitution warning, and the use of CM fonts.

The advantage is, you don't need to modify the code much. And the font is *exacly* Palatino with its mathematical support provided by PSNFSS bundle.

---

Quick solution 2:

```
\renewcommand*\copyright{{%
  \usefont{EU1}{lmr}{m}{n}\textcopyright}}
```

It use the sign in Latin Modern fonts.

This prevents the warnings. And use LMR font for this sign. The font command can be changed as you wish. e.g. `\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont`.

`textcomp` package uses an old set of fonts, in `TS1` font encoding.

---

### Suggested solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}

\begin{document}

Test \copyright 2011
\end{document}
```

Now all fonts are changed to OpenType ones. The result is somewhat similar with pdfLaTeX + `pxfonts` package.

Comment: When you write: "Now all fonts are changed to OpenType ones." I read: "Now all fonts will look different but be OpenType", please tell me I am wrong?

Comment: @jonalv: Now all fonts will look *very few* different but be OpenType.

Answer (score 5):

I'd load **mathpazo** *before* **fontspec**; moreover **fontenc** isn't needed, since you'll want to set the fonts with **fontspec**.

```
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}

\copyright 2011
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the OP wanted to load `mathpazo` with the `OSC` (oldstyle numbers and small caps) option, it might be helpful to include the option `Numbers=OldStyle` in the argument of the `\setmainfont` command. :-)

Comment: @Mico Yes, I'll add it.

Comment: Loading mathpazo before fontspec makes no difference.

Setting the main font to TeX Gyre Pagella brakes small caps and microtype it seems in my code I generated the minimalistic example from... :/

Comment: Okey scratch the small caps issue that is probably because I have code calling `\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont` together with those small caps issues. However I would prefer to not have to rewrite that, also microtype does not work when I load the font in that way it seems... Or do you think it should work and I am doing something wrong?

Comment: With TeX Gyre Pagella, say, Palatino, you should use `unicode-math` with `Asana Math` math font. Note that `mathpazo` also defines math fonts.

Comment: @Leo Liu: Do you have a reference link for me where I can learn more cause I didn't really understand that...

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question about the copyright symbol: The symbol is in the TS1-encoding so you must either load this encoding or the package `textcomp`. The following will work with all engines (pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex ...):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\copyright 2011 
\end{document}
```

But using T1-encoding and the mathpazo textfonts with xelatex is problematic. As you can't use inputenc you will loose the ability to enter non-ascii chars directly. E.g. ß won't work. Hyphenation can be wrong too as the pattern of xelatex are unicode-orientated. It is much better to use as textfonts fonts loaded with fontspec.

Comment: But you have removed the row: `\usepackage{fontspec}` if I add that it does not work. I need it for my sans serif font...

Comment: I have remove `fontspec` because the way you combined the packages is hilarious. How do you intend to set up your sans serif font and switch between the roman and the sans serif font? Do you really intend to switch the font encodings all the time?

Comment: Well, can I not do that? I want to use the mathpazo together with my Optima that ships with my Mac. Also I am using luatex not xetex. It seems that the order I load packages changes the look of the Palatino font though. Seems like fontspec sometimes takes over and overwrites with some other font. It all seems rather complicated...

Comment: Yes fontspec will take over if you load it last, and T1+fontenc+mathpazo will take over if you load fontspec before. In theory you can mix the both font system but you need a lot knowledge to do it right. So in practice I advise you not to do it. Avoid mathpazo for text. Use e.g. TeX Gyre Pagella as suggested and solve whatever problems you got with it.

Comment: Hm, it actually seems to work for me right now. TeX Gyre Pagella won't be used for math as default, also it looked very different when fontspec took over and I guess that's was TeX Gyre Pagella? I don't want that look... 
So I think I will cross all fingers and hope it will continue to work and look as I want it. If not I guess I will be back asking for more help... :) 
After all, my Mac came with a Palatino as well so maybe I should have used that. Still remains the problem with a math font though... right?

Answer (score 0):

I found [a question here on the topic of Copyright symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1676/298). And based on that I came up with a solution which at least for now seems to fulfil all my critera:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\textcopyright \ 2011 
\end{document}
```

Using the `\textcopyright` command seems to work.

Comment: I don't understand why you seem to want to mix commands that are appropriate for compilation under `pdflatex` with others that assume you're going to compile the document under `xelatex`. Either drop the `\usepackage{fontspec}` command entirely (and specify the sans-serif family of your choice separately), or follow the answer provided by @egreg, load the `unicode-math` package in the preamble, and augment his code with something like `\setsansfont{Optima}` (substitute correct font name) and `\setmathfont{Asana Math}`.