# How to insert a trademark symbol? (tm)

Tags: symbols

How do you insert a trademark symbol in LaTeX? That is, the "TM" superscript.

Comment: `\textregistered` creates a ® while `\textsuperscript{TM}` puts `TM` as superscript in text mode.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Package `textcomp` adds symbols with `TS1` encoding and provides symbol `\texttrademark`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\textsuperscript{TM} or \texttrademark
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great thanks! One more question: when I use \texttrademark, the space following it gets removed (even though I include a space after it in the source code). For example, "somenameTMis a..." but I'd like "somenameTM is a..."

Comment: @MD004: `\texttrademark\ is a` (or `\texttrademark{} is a`), see [Space after LaTeX commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/16967).

Comment: Actually even easier is adding a `~` will force latex to add a space.

Comment: @Whitecat `~` can be used, when a line break is to be prevented after the trade mark symbol.

Comment: It's interesting that I tried using \textregistered in a Memoir title with PDFLaTeX and the (R) symbol looks horrible up close. The R is too close to the top of the circle.

Comment: @RickHenderson The outcome of `\textregistered` depends on the font and the font encoding. This [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168938/16967) is about the trade mark symbol. Therefore, `\textregistered` is a little of topic here.

Comment: @RickHenderson See, for example: [how to get good looking copyright and registered symbols](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1676/16967)

Answer (score 23):

Note that LaTeX supports and shows correctly also the ™ character.

(tested with `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`)

Comment: Nice! This is a much neater solution IMO

Answer (score 13):

Just use

```
\textsuperscript{\texttrademark} % for ™
```

and

```
\textsuperscript{\textregistered} % for ®
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `\texttrademark` in the text. The underlying character (for at least most fonts) is already raised off of the line to give a superscript-like appearance.

Spacing notes:

- No space needed between the previous "word." This ensures the TM is properly attached to the text/name.
- Sometimes there is not enough space added *after* the TM mark. In which case you can add curly braces, as in, `\texttrademark{}` and it should work.