# copyright symbol

Tags: copyright

When I use the copyright symbol `$\copyright$` the messages:

```
Missing character: There is no © in font txr!
Missing character: There is no © in font txr!
Missing character: There is no © in font txr!
Missing character: There is no © in font txr!
```

these are displayed in the log file and the symbol is not displayed (why the message is printed four times instead of one)? is there another way to print this symbol? thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Did you load the font with `T1` encoding?

Comment: Please, look this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1677/69174

Comment: do you really want copyright in math mode?

Comment: no, i just want to display the symbol and i thought that it is used in math mode ... this is wrong?

Comment: For text-mode applications, have you tried `\textcopyright`?

Comment: If you add the command `\tracinglostchars=2`, you’ll get the warning message on the console, not just buried in the log file.

Comment: You get it four times because you tried to use the symbol in four different places.

Answer (score 24):

The copyright and other `textcomp` package symbols are not usable in math mode.

In case you want the symbols to appear as a superscript in text mode, you can try to use

```
\textsuperscript{\textcopyright}
```

Comment: As of 2020, this is not correct. The LaTeX kernel defines `\copyright` in both text and math mode.

Answer (score 11):

This is a good example of why questions need a MWE.  Writing `$\copyright$` should have worked. (Sort of: the spacing is wrong because you enter and leave math mode.)  The error message says you were using the font `txr`, which is from `txfonts` and defines this symbol correctly.  (At least, as of 2020, but the package has not been updated since you asked your question.)

Without a MWE or any information about what versions of packages you’re using, it’s impossible to tell what the problem is.

In TeX Live 2020, I get:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\noindent Literal: © \\
Textcomp: \textcopyright \\
{\LaTeXe} (text): \copyright \\
{\LaTeXe} (math): \(\copyright\) \\
TS1: {\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\symbol{"A9}}
\end{document}
```

[image: txfonts]

There’s a newer package to replace `txfonts`, which has not been updated since 2005.  But that shouldn’t make a difference here.  the LaTeX kernel defines `\copyright` to use the same symbol as `\textcopyright` in either text or math mode.  It defines `\textcopyright` in at least four different ways, but the default definition takes the symbol from the 8-bit TS1 encoding.  There is a `TS1txr.fd` in the `txfonts` package, and it contains this symbol.

Either some other package you loaded breaks `\copyright`, or you should upgrade your TeX distribution, or perhaps updating to `fontspec` or `newtxtext` would fix this for you.